# JavaScript postMessage and multiple transferable objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, web-worker, postmessage

I'm trying to use the experimental Canvas feature - offscreenCanvas.

```
index.html

<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </body>

  <script>
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#myCanvas');
    const offscreenCanvas = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();

    const worker = new Worker('./worker.js');
    worker.postMessage({offscreenCanvas}, [offscreenCanvas]);

  </script>
</html>


worker.js

onmessage = e => {
  const ctx = e.data.offscreenCanvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.fillRect(0 , 0, 100 , 100);
  ctx.commit();
}
```

Everything is working fine here, I draw simple rectangle on the canvas. Now - how to pass additional information with postMessage? For example - is it possible to send object with rectangle coordinates?

Like

```
const obj = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
}
```

I tried to use transferable objects by creating new Int8Array:

```
const bufferObj = new Int8Array([obj.x, obj.y]);
```

To be honest I don't know how to send it to worker and read it from the event object. I was thinking about

```
worker.postMessage(offscreenCanvas, bufferObj, [offscreenCanvas, bufferObj]);
```

But this throw an error Value at index 1 does not have a transferable type. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you don't need to *transfer the ownership* of the object, but just send it to the worker, you can do that:

```
const obj = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
}

worker.postMessage({offscreenCanvas, obj}, [offscreenCanvas]);
```

And then just access from the worker to `e.data.obj` without issues. For simple object I would say it's not a major issue, since `postMessage` use [Structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm)

However, if you need optimization, and you pass a large amount of data – as an offscreen canvas – you want to transfer the object on the other side instead.

In such case, your error was using a `Typed Array` that does not implement a `Transferable` interface. You have, instead, to pass the `ArrayBuffer`. For example:

```
const buff = new Uint8Array([obj.x, obj.y]).buffer;

worker.postMessage({offscreenCanvas, buff}, [offscreenCanvas, buff]);
```

That should works.

Comment: You can send the TypedArray as part of the first arg, as long as its buffer is in the second arg, it will get transferred. OP's error was passing the TypedArray directly as the second arg, the postMessage algo gone through each indice of the TypedArray looking for a transferable and found an int => TypeError